# Problema con clase PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, gmail

Estoy tratando de configurar el envió de mail con php a través de la clase PHPMailer. Cuando ejecuto la función que debe enviar el mail me sale el siguiente error:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in.......... on line
>   23

6

la linea 236 es esta: `$mail­->SMTPDebug = 2;`

el codigo completo de la funcion es este:

```
$email=prueba@gmail.com;
$us=Pablo;
mailActivacion($email,$us);
function mailActivacion($dir_correo, $usuario){
  require_once('../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
  //require_once('../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  //indico a la clase que use SMTP
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  //permite modo debug para ver mensajes de las cosas que van ocurriendo
  $mail­->SMTPDebug = 2;
  //Debo de hacer autenticación SMTP
  $mail­->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail­->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
  //indico el servidor de Gmail para SMTP
  $mail­->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  //indico el puerto que usa Gmail
  $mail­->Port = 465;
  //indico un usuario / clave de un usuario de gmail
  $mail­->Username = "micorreo@gmail.com";
  $mail­->Password = "123456789";
  $mail­->SetFrom('micorreo@gmail.com', 'Mi Nombre');
  $mail­->AddReplyTo("micorreo@gmail.com","Mi Nombre");
  $mail­->Subject = "Envío de email usando SMTP de Gmail";
  $mail­->MsgHTML("Hola que tal, esto es el cuerpo del mensaje!");
  //indico destinatario
  $address = $dir_correo;
  $mail­->AddAddress($address, $usuario);
  if(!$mail­->Send()) {
    echo "Error al enviar: " . $mail­>ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Se envía el correo o solo recibes ese warning?

Comment: hola, no se envia el correo, recibo ese error...

Comment: Que version de php, y phpmailer usas?

Comment: PHP 5.5.12 y PHPMailer 5.2.13

Comment: en la primera línea creo que te falta las comillas de esta forma $email='prueba@gmail.com';

Answer (score 1):

Usa esta función:

```
function enviar_correo($destinatarios, $mail_asunto, $mail_contendio, $from, $from_name, $archivos_adjuntos_ruta,$archivos_adjuntos_temp){
$mail= new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$body= $mail_contendio;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the protocol to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "tu.host.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->Subject = $mail_asunto;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$destinatarios=explode(",", $destinatarios);
if(!empty($destinatarios)){
foreach($destinatarios as $un_destinatario){
$mail->AddAddress($un_destinatario); //destinatarios
}
}else{
return false;
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_ruta)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_ruta as $archivo){
$mail->AddAttachment($archivo); // attachment
}
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_temp)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_temp as $nombrearchivo=>$contenidoArchivo){
$mail->AddStringAttachment($contenidoArchivo,$nombrearch ivo,'base64');
}
}
$mail->Timeout = 20;
if($mail->Send()) {
return array(true);
}else {
return array(false,"Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
}
}
$archivos_adjuntos_ruta=array($path1,path2);
$archivos_adjuntos_temp=array(utf8_decode($strfile PDF)=>$strContenidoPdf,utf8_decode($strNomArch)=>$ strContenidoXml);
enviar_correo(...,array(),archivos_adjuntos_temp);//los archivos estan en variables temporales
enviar_correo(...,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,array()) ;//los archivos estan en rutas en disco
enviar_correo(...,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,archivos _adjuntos_temp);//ambas opciones al mismo tiempo
```

Comment: le agregue los parametros de autenticacion y me sale el mismo error, 
  $mail­->Password = "123456789";

Comment: Entonces lo mas probable es que el error este en tus credenciales, o los valores de los parámetros de configuración no sean los que tiene configurado tu servidor de correo, o tengas una versión antigua o con algún bug de phpmailer