# ¿Enviar con phpMailer como attachment un $pdf creado?

Tags: php, pdf

**Expongo claramente el problema:** Mi archivo *.php* hace dos cosas:

1) Crea un pdf (verificado ya, que se almacena en la variable **$pdf**)

2) Envía un email usando **phpMailer.**

**¿El problema?:** El archivo **$pdf** no lo puedo enviar con `$mail->AddAttachment`, ya que **$pdf** no ha tenido su encode. Para lo cual hice lo siguiente:

```
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$pdflisto = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
```

Al tener un "supuesto" **$pdflisto** lo intento enviar por:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($pdflisto, "Cliente.pdf");
```

Pero, a pesar de que llega el email, no llega el attachment.

**¿Qué necesito saber o en qué necesito ayuda?**

¿Qué error estoy cometiendo, *bien sea en el encode o el el addAttachment*, que a través de phpMailer no llega con el archivo adjunto?

Comment: Feliz tarde de nuevo: **Solución del problema**: usar `$mail->addStringAttachment($pdfdoc, 'Cliente.pdf');` donde el String, no necesita el chunk_split. Solo que fuese un String. Obvié la línea dos de `$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$pdflisto = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));` Y lo que se envía es solo el **$pdfdoc** con el **$mail->addStringAttachment**. Espero también sirva para quienes están usando **phpMailer**. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Akyna agrega tu respuesta y explicación, para que sea util a otros usuarios!  vamos! =) saludos!

Comment: Claro... pero soy nueva en esto. ¿Donde hago el post de la explicación? Gracias!!!

Comment: en la parte de abajo, la caja de texto "Tu Respuesta", agregala y marca como resuelta con el tick (no se como se dice en español).ç

Answer (score 4):

**Solución del problema:** usar `$mail->addStringAttachment($pdfdoc, 'Cliente.pdf');` donde el String, **no necesita el chunk_split**. 
Solo que fuese un String.

Obvié la línea dos de

```
             $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S"); 
             pdflisto = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
```

Y lo que se envía es solo el **$pdfdoc** con el `$mail->addStringAttachment.` Espero también sirva para quienes están usando phpMailer.

Answer (score 1):

No eliminen las dos lineas solo una

```
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S"); 
pdflisto = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
```

debería ser así

```
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
```

yo lo realicé y funcionó perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Este es mi código y funciona perfectamente.

```
<?php $message =ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
include("../../libs/mpdf/mpdf.php"); //Include mPDF Class 

$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$emailAttachment = $mpdf->Output('','S');
//$emailAttachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($emailAttachment));    

 require_once('phpmailer1/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('phpmailer1/class.smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//From email address and name
$mail->From = "fg@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "fgfgf.com - Factura Virtual";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress("fgf@gmail.com");

//Address to which recipient will reply

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
$mail->AddStringAttachment($emailAttachment, 'file.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');// attachment
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Siempre es bueno explicar un poco el código, para que quede documentado y sea de ayuda para otros usuarios, tu respuesta sería mejor aceptada si das explicación de porque tu respuesta soluciona el problema, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre que podrías guardar el fichero temporalmente, ya que necesitamos su ruta para incluirlo como adjunto en el email.

Te dejo la función correcta para este caso que planteas:

```
   $mail->AddAttachment('carpeta_del_fichero_pdf', $name = 'NombreDelFichero',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa esta función:

```
function enviar_correo($destinatarios, $mail_asunto, $mail_contendio, $from, $from_name, $archivos_adjuntos_ruta,$archivos_adjuntos_temp){
$mail= new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$body= $mail_contendio;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the protocol to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "tu.host.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->Subject = $mail_asunto;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$destinatarios=explode(",", $destinatarios);
if(!empty($destinatarios)){
foreach($destinatarios as $un_destinatario){
$mail->AddAddress($un_destinatario); //destinatarios
}
}else{
return false;
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_ruta)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_ruta as $archivo){
$mail->AddAttachment($archivo); // attachment
}
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_temp)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_temp as $nombrearchivo=>$contenidoArchivo){
$mail->AddStringAttachment($contenidoArchivo,$nombrearch ivo,'base64');
}
}
$mail->Timeout = 20;
if($mail->Send()) {
return array(true);
}else {
return array(false,"Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
}
}
$archivos_adjuntos_ruta=array($path1,path2);
$archivos_adjuntos_temp=array(utf8_decode($strfile PDF)=>$strContenidoPdf,utf8_decode($strNomArch)=>$ strContenidoXml);
enviar_correo(...,array(),archivos_adjuntos_temp);//los archivos estan en variables temporales
enviar_correo(...,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,array()) ;//los archivos estan en rutas en disco
enviar_correo(...,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,archivos _adjuntos_temp);//ambas opciones al mismo tiempo
```

Comment: Hola @abrahamhs. Por favor brinda el contenido relevante del código a utilizar y una explicación del mismo. Sé que has brindado **la misma respuesta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9138/227)**, y aunque sea contenido creado por tí, no tiene mucho uso si sólo copias y pegas contenido de manera aleatoria sin brindar ninguna explicación.